Mail Accounts, bounce processing: Failed to connect to the server: email-smtp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:993
This  issue has been popping out now and then. It is Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 5.76.1.
Same SMTP Credentials works for civicrm/admin/setting/smtp?reset=1 but the "Save & test" at civicrm/admin/mailSettings?reset=1 (IMAP + Use SSL) returns

"[exception] => ezcMailTransportException: "An error occured while
sending or receiving mail. Failed to connect to the server:
email-smtp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:993."

Both commands below return time-outs ( see  the docs )

openssl s_client -connect email-smtp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:993
telnet email-smtp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com 993

Messing with ports (587/465) at www/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/zetacomponents/mail/src/transports/imap/imap_transport.php:401  doesn't help much: the 465 responded with "An error occured while sending or receiving mail. The connection to the IMAP server is ok, but a negative response from server was received. Try again later."
The issue has been happening for a while, the server is set to be checked once in a 3 months so it is not because of the most recent CiviCRM 5.76.1 upgrade. Summer IMAP changes at Amazon perhaps?
Please advise, thanks!

email-smtp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com sounds like an OUTBOUND mail server, so probably doesn't have IMAP open. You'll need to look up the right imap server for your account. Maybe it's one of these: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/userguide/using_IMAP.html
